# Equivalent SQL Query using Cartesian Product Only

Tags: sql, sql-server

*given 3 tables a : `{id, name_eng}, b: {id, name_spa} and c: {id, name_ita}`
which is the equivalent "product cartesian query" for this given one:*

```
select
    a.name_eng
    b.name_spa
    c.name_ita
from
    a inner join b on a.id = b.id
    left outer join c on a.id = c.id
```

Comment: What is the result you are looking for, or is this just a homework question? :)  By cartesian product you would be referring to a query where each row is paired with every row of the other table...in this case the result could be quite large and you would use a cross join: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_9_sql_cross_join.htm

Comment: Is not a homework question. I give 3 tables as an example because mine tables are in the order o 5 with many fields. I'm supporting a software change and the previous developer design a query with cartesian product, I changed to an equivalent using inner and left outer ('cause of the requirements). But after finished I whish to know if there is a way to make a query like the above typed in a simpler way (using only cartesian product).

Comment: Are you sure you really want the "cartesian product"?  Where every row of each table is combined with each row of the other tables?  With just 10 rows in each table your result would be 1000 rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want, a cartesian product would be this:

```
SELECT  a.name_eng
        b.name_spa
        c.name_ita
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
CROSS JOIN c
```

Or the implicit way:

```
SELECT  a.name_eng
        b.name_spa
        c.name_ita
FROM a,b,c
```

If you want your previous query written with cartesian products (why??), then this should do (on SQL Server 2000):

```
SELECT  a.name_eng
        b.name_spa
        c.name_ita
FROM a,b,c
WHERE a.id = b.id 
AND a.id *= c.id
```

If I wasn't clear enough with the "why??", you shouldn't use implicit joins since hey are deprecated, you should always use proper explicit joins.

Comment: Excelent. the operator *= is what the one I was looking for @Lamak :) And i wrote an equivalent one because of the company database (SQL Server 2000). But I didn't remember that litte piece of "sql-code"

Comment: `*=` is Microsoft's operator for an outer join. Don't use it, it's deprecated and bad style. Use a proper `left outer join` instead.

Comment: Yep, I'm working on the company apps migration an unfortunately I got to deal with this issue. I've change a couple of queries with that stingy style. @a_horse_with_no_name tnx for your advice. :)